# filter nested json column on multiple values rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord

The JSON which is stored in the database column looks similar to

```
"data": {
  "player": {
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "team": "London Blues"
  }
}
```

and in my view I would like to have a search field, which accepts first name last name or a team name and filters the list accordingly. At the moment I have the following solution which I am not really satisfied and if there is any better ways to do it please share :)

```
PlayerReqeust.where("initial -> 'data'  -> 'player' ->> 'firstName'  LIKE ? or initial -> 'data'  -> 'player' ->> 'lastName  LIKE ? or initial -> 'data'  -> 'player' ->> 'team  LIKE ?", "%John%", "%John%", "%John%")
```